# getting a sub-dataframe from values

Tags: python, pandas

i'm working with timeseries data with this format:

```
[timestamp][rain value]
```

i wanted to count rainfall events in the timeseries data, where we define a rainfall event as a subdataframe of the main dataframe which contains nonzero values between zero rainfall values

i managed to get the start of the dataframe by getting the index of rainfall value before the first nonzero value:

```
start = df.rain.values.nonzero()[0][0] - 1
cur = df[start:]
```

what i can't figure out is how to find the end. i was looking for some function zero():

```
end=cur.rain.values.zero()[0][0]
```

to find the next zero value in the rain column and mark that as the end of my subdataframe

additionally, because my data is sampled at 15min intervals, it would mean that a temporary lull of 15mins would give me two rainfall events instead of one, which realistically isn't true. which means i would like to define some time period - 6hrs for example - to separate rainfall events.

what i was thinking of (but could not execute because i couldn't find the `end` of the subdataframe yet), in pseudocode:

```
start = df.rain.values.nonzero()[0][0] - 1
cur = df[start:]

end=cur.rain.values.zero()[0][0]

temp = df[end:]
z = temp.rain.values.nonzero()[0][0] - 1

if timedelta (z-end) >=6hrs:
    end stays as endpoint of cur
else:
    z is new endpoint, find next nonzero to again check
```

so i guess my question is, how do i find the `end` of my subdataframe if i don't want to iterate over all rows

and am i on the right track with my pseudocode in defining the end of a rainfall event as, say, 6 hours of 0 rain.

Comment: Sorry are you after `df[df['rain']==0].index[0]`?

Comment: @EdChum
hey thanks, this worked. another question, though. how do increment/decrement a datetimeindex? for example, i did this to find the start of my dataframe
 
`start = rain[rain['rain']!=0].index[0]`
 
but that will cause me to start on a non-zero value. so i wanted to do something like
 
`start = rain[rain['rain']!=0].index[0] - 1`
 
to go on to the last zero value before the nonzero. can't seem to find the offset thing i was trying to look for.
 
thanks!

Comment: You can use `.get_loc` to return you the ordinal index position so for in your case `start_idx_pos = rain,index.get_loc(rain[rain['rain']!=0].index[0])` you can then do `start = rain.iloc[start_idx_pos -1].index[0]`

Comment: hey, that worked too, thanks. can you post it as an answer so i can mark it?